# Android Screen OFF / ON

Tags: java, android, screen

I need to get my screen turned on/off using SensorEventListener when

```
    @Override
    public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.values[0] == 0)
            turnScreenOFF();
        else if (event.values[0] == 5)
            turnScreenON();
    }
```

I have tried many sample code for it, but I can't get my screen turned ON again after it's turned OFF

There is the code to turn off the screen :

```
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        params.screenBrightness = 0.0f;
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

For screen on-off state, you can try with `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` intents,which will come in nifty if you’re making an application that might need to save state or respond to the user’s screen going to sleep/waking up, etc.

Check out the [Handling Screen ON/OFF.](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/)

**EDITED:**

Try out below:

```
 private void unlockScreen() {
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    }
```

And call this method from `onResume()`.

Comment: I don't need to handle when screen is on or is off, but I need to turn the screen ON programatically after it's turned OFF by the above code.

Comment: For more details check http://android.okhelp.cz/turn-screen-on-off-android-sample-code/

Comment: Doesn't work, you can try and edit the source :
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8lfr4yeb90h31ib/TestAndroidProject.zip)

Comment: I need a working source code ASAP, someone can help me please ?